# Why do both javac (compiler) and java (JVM) need a mention of external dependencies in the classpath?

Tags: java, jvm

If a java source file is dependent on an external JAR file, we need to provide the path of the external dependency to the java compiler:

```
javac -cp [path-to-external-JAR] foo.java

jar cvf foo.jar foo.class
```

Again, when we need to execute this jar file, we need to provide the path of the external dependency to the JVM:

```
java -cp [path-to-external-JAR]:foo.jar foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler needs the reference because it has to check that the classes and methods you're calling or overriding exist, and can be called/overridden.

The JVM needs them because it has to execute the instructions inside these classes and methods.

Comment: So, if i move the external dependency to a new location after compilation and use the new path with the JVM, would that create a problem ?

Comment: No. The classes need to be in the classpath, that's all.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously java (vm) needs the class definition to run. Javac needs the class declarations for type information...

> To process the source code they operate on, javac and javadoc must
>   obtain information on object types used in the source code.

[Reference- Oracle Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/findingclasses.html)

Answer (score 0):

otherwise it has to endup searching your entire filesystem for the external classes you used in the application.